# mootools: find all instances of Accordion object?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a page which creates several mootools Accordion objects in joomla.
It's mootools 1.2.5 in Jooma 1.5

As far as I understand, javascript does not provide an elegant way to find all instances of a certain class. I'd have to modify the code to create a global array or list of each instance which is appended to each time a new instance is created, and then iterate through this list.

I wondered if mootools has a utility function which already tracks collections of its objects? 
(I want to collapse all other accordions when one is expanded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a lot of mootools classes save references to themselves inside of element storage. not so with Fx.Accordion.

you can probably find if a variable has Fx.accordion as its constructor, but there are no guarantees there will be such - its not uncommon to just run the class constructor w/o saving a reference.

probably the easiest thing would be to refactor the Fx.Accordion constructor and get it to write a copy of the instance in the main element or wherever - to keep reference.

eg,

```
var orig = Fx.Accordion.initialize;
Fx.Accordion.initialize = function() {
    orig.apply(this, arguments);
    this.element.store("accordion", this); // or... 
    // window.accordions.push(this);
};
```

Comment: thanks. I decided to use the window approach, with a test to create an empty list if necessary.